# Open GUI for running script

Tags: python, user-interface, daemon

I have Python script running as service(24/7). This script is executed by LaunchDaemon on start. I would like to implement GUI for this script so I could check progress. How can I recognize my script is running and just open thread with GUI when I start that script again?

Thank You

Comment: This question is extremely ambiguous.

Comment: I have script without gui, it's basically simple tcp server. This scrip is running until I exit it with ctrl+c. When this script receives some data it writes to sqlite database it. What I want is some way how to open again than script and show gui interface with information from db.

Answer (score -1):

You could look at Tkinter to run at start up? Using a simple if running display "running" else display "error"

Comment: On my mobile so can't give example code but Google tkinter as there's lots of info